# Blocking Websites/Apps on Samsung s6 [G920VVRS4CQA3]

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6, call-screening

After researching all day how to root my specific build number of the Samsung Galaxy s6, a G920VVRS4CQA3, it seems it cannot be done (safely, at least) due to the locked bootloader that comes with the Verizon and AT&T models. I looked into all kinds of different methods but to no avail. (I wanted to root the phone in order to edit the host file and block webpages.)

So, I wanted to ask - **what is the best alternative to blocking SPECIFIC apps and SPECIFIC webpages on the android device?** I need an app or method that doesn't scream "this app/webpage is blocked due to parental control." I'd like something more discrete that would just lead to a message claiming "server not found" or something of the sort. I am not looking to block ads or filter out an entire category of the internet, I just need a way to block specific websites and apps on the playstore that cannot be easily tampered with. Something with a passcode.

*Alternatively, if you have been able to root the G920VVRS4CQA3, I'd greatly appreciate knowing how to went about doing it.*

Thanks

Comment: by "blocking specific apps", do you mean to forbid internet access for those particular apps while the rest continue to have internet. For this you need a firewall application (eg NoRoot firewall from playstore). If you wish to block some websites (or IP addresses) , you might need to run your own DNS Server  on your device and add rules for the DNS Server (give an IP for a set host or block certain hosts) not entirely sure if root is a requirement though